# Conjugacy classes of two elements of order $p$ in a simple group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G$ be a non abelian simple group and $x,~y$ be two elements of order $p$ of $G$, where $p$ is a prime. Suppose $|x^G|\neq |y^G|$. Is there any relation between $|x^G|$ and $|y^G|$? For example is it true that $|x^G|$ divides $|y^G|$ or vice versa?

$x^G$ is the conjugacy class of $x$ in $G$, i.e. $~x^G=\{g^{-1}xg:~ g\in G\}$.

Comment: By $\;p$-elements you mean elements with order $\;p\;$ or order *a power* of  $\;p\;$ ? ($\;p=$ a prime, I presume...)

Comment: @mt_ The smallest nonabelian simple group is $A_5$, and $A_5$ does not have any pair of elements $x,y$ having the same order with $|x^G| \ne |y^G|$, so it cannot be a counterexample.

Comment: @DerekHolt oops, misread the question!

Comment: @mt_ Like DonAntonio I am unsure what $p$-element means here.

Comment: $(1~2) \notin A_5$

Comment: @Derek: Either you or Jack could probably easily either give the argument or a link to the result about solvable transitive subgroups of $S_p$ that is needed in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/618117/11619). Adeleh, sorry about using your question to summon a group theorist.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've added a reasonably detailed answer to that question.

Comment: Thanks, @Derek. (+1) to all involved in that as well as this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the alternating group $G$ of degree 9, there are two conjugacy classes of elements of order $2$: $x=(1,2)(3,4)$ and $y=(1,2)(3,4)(5,6)(7,8)$. Neither class size divides the other: $|x^G| = 2\cdot 3^3 \cdot 7$ and $|y^G|=3^3\cdot 5 \cdot 7$; the first is divisible by 2 but the second is not, and the second is divisible by 5 but the first is not. $p=3$ also works for this group.

Here are the small examples, up to $|G| \leq 10^{10}$. “leftover” is a semi-colon separated list of class sizes divided by the GCD of the class sizes (given in the previous column). $$\begin{array}{cccl}
G & p & \gcd & \textrm{leftover} \\ \hline
M_{12} & 2 & 3^2\cdot11 & 2^2; 5 \\
M_{12} & 3 & 2^4\cdot5\cdot11 & 2; 3 \\
A_9 & 2 & 3^3\cdot7 & 2; 5 \\
A_9 & 3 & 2^3\cdot7 & 3; 2^2\cdot3\cdot5; 2^3\cdot5 \\
PSp_6(2) & 3 & 2^5\cdot7 & 3; 2^2\cdot3\cdot5; 2\cdot5 \\
A_{10} & 2 & 3^2\cdot5\cdot7 & 2; 3\cdot5 \\
A_{10} & 3 & 2^4\cdot5 & 3; 3\cdot5\cdot7; 2^3\cdot5\cdot7 \\
PSU_3(8) & 3 & 2^6\cdot19 & 3; 3; 2^3\cdot7 \\
PSL_4(3) & 2 & 3^4\cdot13 & 5; 2 \\
PSL_5(2) & 3 & 2^7\cdot31 & 5; 2\cdot7 \\
{}^2F_4(2) & 2 & 3^2\cdot5\cdot13 & 2^2\cdot5; 3 \\
A_{11} & 2 & 3^2\cdot5\cdot11 & 2; 5\cdot7 \\
A_{11} & 3 & 2\cdot5\cdot11 & 3; 2^3\cdot3\cdot7; 2^5\cdot5\cdot7 \\
HS & 2 & 5^2\cdot7\cdot11 & 3; 2^3 \\
HS & 5 & 2^7\cdot3\cdot7\cdot11 & 3; 5; 2^2\cdot3\cdot5 \\
J_3 & 3 & 2^4\cdot17\cdot19 & 3^2; 2^3\cdot5 \\
\Omega^+_8(2) & 2 & 3^2\cdot5\cdot7 & 2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5; 5; 2^2\cdot3; 2^2\cdot3; 2^2\cdot3 \\
\Omega^-_8(2) & 3 & 2^6\cdot17 & 3; 2^3\cdot3\cdot7; 2^3\cdot5\cdot7 \\
{}^3D_4(2) & 3 & 2^9\cdot7\cdot13 & 7; 3 \\
M_{24} & 2 & 3^2\cdot11\cdot23 & 5; 2\cdot7 \\
M_{24} & 3 & 2^7\cdot11\cdot23 & 3\cdot5; 7 \\
PSL_4(4) & 3 & 2^6\cdot17 & 5; 5; 2^2\cdot3\cdot7; 2^4\cdot3\cdot5\cdot7 \\
PSL_4(4) & 5 & 2^8\cdot3^2\cdot7 & 2^2\cdot17; 2^2\cdot17; 2^4\cdot3\cdot17; 3; 3 \\
PSU_4(4) & 3 & 2^8\cdot5\cdot13 & 2^2\cdot17; 5 \\
PSU_4(4) & 5 & 2^6\cdot17 & 2^4\cdot3\cdot13 ~ (6 \textrm{ classes}); \\ & & &  3  ~ (4 \textrm{ classes}); \\ & & &  2^2\cdot13 ~ (2 \textrm{ classes}); \\ & & & 2^6\cdot3^2\cdot13 \\
PSU_3(17) & 3 & 7\cdot13\cdot17^2 & 3; 3; 2^4\cdot17 \\
He & 2 & 3\cdot5\cdot7^2\cdot17 & 2; 3\cdot5 \\
He & 7 & 2^7\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot17 & 2^2\cdot3\cdot7; 2^2\cdot3\cdot7; 2^3; 7; 7 \\
PSp_6(3) & 2 & 3^4\cdot13 & 7; 2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5 \\
\Omega_7(3) & 3 & 2^3\cdot7\cdot13 & 
2\cdot5;  \\ &&&
2^2\cdot3^2;  \\ &&&
2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5 ~(2\textrm{ classes}); \\ &&&
2^4\cdot3^3\cdot5; \\ &&&
2^5\cdot3^3\cdot5 \\ &&&
3^2\cdot5; \\
PSL_3(19) & 3 & 19^2\cdot127 & 2^2\cdot5\cdot19; 3; 3 \\
PSL_4(5) & 3 & 2^3\cdot5^4\cdot31 & 5\cdot13; 2 \\
PSU_6(2) & 3 & 2^9\cdot7\cdot11 & 5; 3; 2^3\cdot3\cdot5 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Either you or Derek could probably easily either give the argument or a link to the result about solvable transitive subgroups of $S_p$ that is needed in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/618117/11619). Adeleh, sorry about using your question to summon a group theorist.

Comment: Thank you for your very nice and detailed answer.

Comment: Jack, nice answer! +1